Extra space on the right side before the actual margin in Microsoft excel
my worksheet content in excel is fully distributed (width wise) and is touching the page breaks (left & right) which are dashed lines . The thing that I am not getting is that the content is fully distributed (width wise) and is touching the page breaks (left & right), but while viewing the worksheet in print preview, there is a space on the right before the margin. I am not excepting that space as the content on the worksheet is fully distributed (width wise) and is touching the page breaks (left & right). so why there is a space on the right before the margin (form where it comes from)


What do you mean by fully distributed? What are the print settings for your print range?

By fully distributed, I mean that my worksheet content is fully covering the page area (width wise) leaving no space at left and right and is touches the page breaks from left and right. But in print preview, I see the space on right before the margin. My print settings are: (Print active sheets and margins are normal, Portrait Orientation, A4 Size, No Scaling)

What happens if you fit to one page wide and leave # of pages high/long blank?

I noticed the heading Percentage has text outside of the page break. What happens if you widen just column G so the text fits?
